# Create data frame from EFA output in R

Tags: r, psych, factor-analysis

I am working on EFA and would like to customize my tables. There is a function, `psych.print` to suppress factor loadings of a certain value to make the table easier to read. When I run this function, it produces this data and the summary stats in the console (in an .RMD document, it produces console text and a separate data frame of the factor loadings with loadings suppressed). However, if I attempt to save this as an object, it does not keep this data.

Here is an example:

```
library(psych)
bfi_data=bfi

bfi_data=bfi_data[complete.cases(bfi_data),]

bfi_cor <- cor(bfi_data)


factors_data <- fa(r = bfi_cor, nfactors = 6)
print.psych(fa_ml_oblimin_2, cut=.32, sort="TRUE")
```

In an R script, it produces this:

```
          item   MR2   MR3   MR1   MR5   MR4   MR6    h2   u2 com
N2          17  0.83                               0.654 0.35 1.0
N1          16  0.82                               0.666 0.33 1.1
N3          18  0.69                               0.549 0.45 1.1
N5          20  0.47                               0.376 0.62 2.2
N4          19  0.44        0.43                   0.506 0.49 2.4
C4           9       -0.67                         0.555 0.45 1.3
C2           7        0.66                         0.475 0.53 1.4
C5          10       -0.56                         0.433 0.57 1.4
C3           8        0.56                         0.317 0.68 1.1
C1           6        0.54                         0.344 0.66 1.3
```

In R Markdown, it produces this:
[image]

How can I save that data.frame as an object?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure (since you didn't add reproducible examples), but try object_name <- as.table(print.psych(fa_ml_oblimin_2, cut=.32, sort="TRUE")).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the `str` of the object it doesn't look that what you want is built-in. An ugly way would be to use `capture.output` and try to convert the character vector to dataframe using string manipulation. Else since the data is being displayed it means that the data is present somewhere in the object itself. I could find out vectors of same length which can be combined to form the dataframe.

```
loadings <- unclass(factors_data$loadings)
h2 <- factors_data$communalities
#There is also factors_data$communality which has same values
u2 <- factors_data$uniquenesses
com <- factors_data$complexity
data <- cbind(loadings, h2, u2, com)
data
```

This returns :

```
#            MR2   MR3   MR1   MR5   MR4   MR6   h2   u2  com
#A1         0.11  0.07 -0.07 -0.56 -0.01  0.35 0.38 0.62 1.85
#A2         0.03  0.09 -0.08  0.64  0.01 -0.06 0.47 0.53 1.09
#A3        -0.04  0.04 -0.10  0.60  0.07  0.16 0.51 0.49 1.26
#A4        -0.07  0.19 -0.07  0.41 -0.13  0.13 0.29 0.71 2.05
#A5        -0.17  0.01 -0.16  0.47  0.10  0.22 0.47 0.53 2.11
#C1         0.05  0.54  0.08 -0.02  0.19  0.05 0.34 0.66 1.32
#C2         0.09  0.66  0.17  0.06  0.08  0.16 0.47 0.53 1.36
#C3         0.00  0.56  0.07  0.07 -0.04  0.05 0.32 0.68 1.09
#C4         0.07 -0.67  0.10 -0.01  0.02  0.25 0.55 0.45 1.35
#C5         0.15 -0.56  0.17  0.02  0.10  0.01 0.43 0.57 1.41
#E1        -0.14  0.09  0.61 -0.14 -0.08  0.09 0.41 0.59 1.34
#E2         0.06 -0.03  0.68 -0.07 -0.08 -0.01 0.56 0.44 1.07
#E3         0.02  0.01 -0.32  0.17  0.38  0.28 0.51 0.49 3.28
#E4        -0.07  0.03 -0.49  0.25  0.00  0.31 0.56 0.44 2.26
#E5         0.16  0.27 -0.39  0.07  0.24  0.04 0.41 0.59 3.01
#N1         0.82 -0.01 -0.09 -0.09 -0.03  0.02 0.67 0.33 1.05
#N2         0.83  0.02 -0.07 -0.07  0.01 -0.07 0.65 0.35 1.04
#N3         0.69 -0.03  0.13  0.09  0.02  0.06 0.55 0.45 1.12
#N4         0.44 -0.14  0.43  0.09  0.10  0.01 0.51 0.49 2.41
#N5         0.47 -0.01  0.21  0.21 -0.17  0.09 0.38 0.62 2.23
#O1        -0.05  0.07 -0.01 -0.04  0.57  0.09 0.36 0.64 1.11
#O2         0.12 -0.09  0.01  0.12 -0.43  0.28 0.30 0.70 2.20
#O3         0.01  0.00 -0.10  0.05  0.65  0.04 0.48 0.52 1.06
#O4         0.10 -0.05  0.34  0.15  0.37 -0.04 0.24 0.76 2.55
#O5         0.04 -0.04 -0.02 -0.01 -0.50  0.30 0.33 0.67 1.67
#gender     0.20  0.09 -0.12  0.33 -0.21 -0.15 0.18 0.82 3.58
#education -0.03  0.01  0.05  0.11  0.12 -0.22 0.07 0.93 2.17
#age       -0.06  0.07 -0.02  0.16  0.03 -0.26 0.10 0.90 2.05
```

Comment: Thanks. That works great. It helped me write the function below to make a cleaner data table of the results, though I have not figured out how to sort it in the best way:

Answer (score 0):

Ronak Shaw answered my question above, and I used his answer to help create the following function, which nearly reproduces the `psych.print` data.frame of `fa.sort` output

```
fa_table <- function(x, cut) {
  #get sorted loadings
  loadings <- fa.sort(fa_ml_oblimin)$loadings %>% round(3)
  #cut loadings
  loadings[loadings < cut] <- ""
  #get additional info
  add_info <- cbind(x$communalities, 
                    x$uniquenesses,
                    x$complexity) %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    rename("commonality" = V1,
           "uniqueness" = V2,
           "complexity" = V3) %>%
    rownames_to_column("item")
  #build table
  loadings %>%
    unclass() %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    rownames_to_column("item") %>%
    left_join(add_info) %>%
    mutate(across(where(is.numeric), round, 3))
}
```